# Partial $routeProvider AngularJS is not working?

Tags: angularjs

So, I getting started learn about AngularJS which version 1.2.26 and I have issue when I try to learn partial using $routeProvider.

Issue : when I click the button Kart or Books is not working and the console.log is clean (not result error)

Here about my source code:

Angular : http://pastebin.com/s10VRr1W
HTML5 : http://pastebin.com/kvUjmt9T

Comment: Add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in config and where you declare HeaderCtrl you used in `ng-controller`

Comment: need your controller and view to help you debug.